# Polynomial annihilator method $y''+4y=\sin^2(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

The question asks to solve the equation by this method.

I know how to annihilate $\sin(2x)$ by $(D^2+4)$ however i don't know for the case $\sin^2(2x)$.

Thanks!

Comment: How about expressing $\sin^2(2x)$ in terms of $\cos(4x)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** If you know how to annihilate $\sin(2x)$, you surely know how to annihilate $\sin^2(2x)$, you just write
$$
\sin^2(2x)=\frac{1-\cos (4x)}{2}
$$ then you annihilate $ \cos (4x)$ as you did for  $\sin(2x)$, obtaining
$$
(D^2+16)(\cos (4x))\equiv0
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the identity

> $$ \sin(t) = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} $$